# How do I fetch values in React and use it as a autocomplete list in Materialize?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I am trying to create a autocomplete list using Materialize that is populated with a fetch method. However I am not seeing this work. 
I initialized materialize autocomplete on index.html:

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
  data: {
    "Apple": null,
    "Microsoft": null,
    "Google": null
  },
```

however, I would like to initialize it when I get all of the data fetched by the component.

```
componentDidMount(){
   fetch('example.com').then(response => {
      $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: response
   })
}
```

However, it doesnt work. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What does `response` look like?

Comment: I dont know. It's just a supposition. The problem is that I am not able to use jquery inside of componentDidMount. it says "autocomplete is not a function". So I don't know how to make this work

Comment: I'm guessing it gives you the error `$(...).autocomplete is not a function`? If so, you may not have the plugin installed correctly. Are you able to set an autocomplete in that way anywhere else in the application?

Comment: Yes. on index.html but not inside react components

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/p73z66zl47 Check this.

Comment: Thank you @GermaVinsmoke